# Reading .evtx files in JAVA

Tags: java, spring, windows

I'm trying to find the best way to read .evtx files in JAVA the only almost valid solution I found is parsing it to a csv file using windows power shell (takes about a minute to parse a file with 250 lines) and then reading the csv file with missing data.

is there any better options for reading evtx files in JAVA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check an open source library [here](https://formats.kaitai.io/windows_evt_log/java.html).
It parses **evt** files (old version of Windows event log), not sure if it will tackle **evtx** files.